# Ubuntu alternative to Thunderbird now that Mozilla dropped support

Tags: thunderbird, email

What Ubuntu's plan to Mail client now that Mozilla dropped support of Thunderbird?

Comment: They merely said that it is not getting any new features. Finally! They are just going to make it more stable. So why abandon a fully featured, rather stable client? I do not see the point why we always have to use something that is still in development, and not something that is rather finished.

Comment: There is still support and will be support for Thunderbird. What we will not find and I agree with queueoverflow is more features since they added a few bugs each time a feature was added. So what we will start seeing is Thunderbird but with more bugs fixed.

Comment: What about other alternatives though. I'll try evolution although I just want a lightweight but reasonably featured GUI mail client. Thunderbird used to be great, but over the years it got bloaty and now it crashes every once in a while and it freezes up for 10 seconds at a time. Is there no real alternative to thunderbird?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Mozilla has NOT dropped support for Thunderbird, they simply won't be adding any new features to it except security updates

Mozilla has [only said](http://blog.lizardwrangler.com/2012/07/06/thunderbird-stability-and-community-innovation/) that *their developers* will not be working on Thunderbird *further*, i.e. adding new features, etc after 20 Nov 2012. They *will* continue making security updates available for Thunderbird until [30 December 2013](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/organizations/faq/).

At the same time, outside developers ("the community") can continue working on a parallel version of Thunderbird (still released by Mozilla) which will include new features, etc.

---

Considering that Mozilla.org involvement in developing Thunderbird will stop only *after* Quantal is released, it's a little early to begin looking about for alternatives. Even if the community doesn't pick up the slack and Thunderbird begins to go obsolete, I'm sure that Canonical will have an alternative in place by the R-series (April 2013).

Answer (score 2):

[Evolution](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/evolution/) is Seamless , try that.

> Evolution is a groupware suite which integrates mail, calendar,
>   address book, to-do list and memo tools.Additional features include
>   integration with Exchange servers, newsgroup client, LDAP support and
>   web calendars

[image]

And their is  [Unity Mail](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unity-mail/) , it makes login available through Unity mail Application , but opens in Web Browser.

For Further officially available try [this](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/department/mail/) .

Also a new Mail client [Geary](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/05/new-e-mail-client-geary-launches-on-linux) is launched , but in [Development](http://redmine.yorba.org/projects/geary/wiki/) , needs Third Party PPA though.

As far as **Ubuntu Quantal 12.10 is concerned no such Official Announcement** has been made yet. If you want to keep track then refer the [Ubuntu Quantal Blueprints](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal) and [Launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal).

But currently in **Alpha releases** Thunderbird is Default Client.

Comment: What is going to be Ubuntu default client post 12.04?

Comment: Edited, See Answer .It is not yet decided , might be announced in Near future..

Comment: Is there an option Canonical will support Thunderbird?

Comment: Yes likely possible , because Ubuntu 12.04 has by default Thunderbird, it is an LTS release , they might support it. But since the source itself will not be contributed ,hence  can't say so. Also this gives you lot of experience with other options available.

Answer (score 2):

Judging by [this blueprint](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/desktop-p-thunderbird-enhancements) currently targeted for the Quantal cycle, Mozilla's dropping of Thunderbird has caught people working on Ubuntu by surprise.

Default applications are usually discussed at Ubuntu Desktop Summits, and the next one is after Quantal is released. My guess is that Quantal may either ship with Thunderbird or switch back to Evolution (which was the previous default email client). This issue also affects the current 12.04 LTS, so this is likely to be brought up at the next UDS to offer a 12.04.x revision with a supported email client.

All of the above is speculative, of course.